# Formatted number range filter - jquery datatable

Tags: datatables

I have a data-table with value in one column like $0.00, $2,000.00 and so on. How i will do the range filtering for this. Like filter all records between $0.00 to $1,000.00.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Yet Another DataTables Column Filter (Yadcf)](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) plugin

Take a look at the example, in short all you need it to use `filter_type: "range_number"` for your column.

Take a look at the examples and the docs in the *jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js* file