# Angular Datatables number-range filter not working with non-number characters

Tags: angularjs, datatables, filtering

I am using **Angular Data-tables**, with **column filters**, in my project (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables).
I have a problem with the **number-range filter** not working when other characters (other than numbers) are present in the filtered column. I've been looking for a solution for a while now, but with no luck. (I tried this too [Formatted number range filter - jquery datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447093/formatted-number-range-filter-jquery-datatable))

```
<!-- PRICE NOT FILTERED -->
<td class="text-left">
{{ price.replace(',','') | currency:'$' }}
</td>   

<!-- PRICE FILTERED CORRECTLY -->
<td class="text-left">
{{ price.replace(',','') }}
</td> 

// define options for the datatables tool - with column filtering
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('order', [[4, 'desc']])
    .withOption("sDom", '<<t>lip>')
    .withColumnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [        
        {
            type: 'number-range'
        }, ...
]
});
```

[image]

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: you can write a custom filter

Comment: @Ioana were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately, for this and several other reasons I had to write my own custom solution for table filtering, ordering and rendering - not related to Angular Datatables.